# How can I start this inside observable to execute on the right time but not later

Tags: angular

Do you know how to execute the second one at the right time, because the first observable does its job and goes directly to the return method. And later after that the code executes the second observable and I want to be paralel.

```
hasEditRechte(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.zugriffsrechte = [];
    this.getCurrentBenutzer().subscribe(result => {
        this.currentLoggedInBenutzer = result;
        this.getBenutzerRolleDTO(this.currentLoggedInBenutzer.id).subscribe(benutzerDTO => {
            this.zugriffsrechte = benutzerDTO.zugriffsrechte;
        });
    });
    return of(this.rolleService.hasEditZugriffRechte(this.zugriffsrechte));
}
```

**  -> this one comes later but I want before to return already to have the result from here              this.zugriffsrechte = benutzerDTO.zugriffsrechte;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this code, but I think you should use switchMap or switchMapTo and avoid using nested subscribe. [This could help](https://angular-checklist.io/default/checklist/rxjs/Z1eFwa9)

```
hasEditRechte(): Observable<boolean> {
  this.zugriffsrechte = [];
  return this.getCurrentBenutzer().pipe(
    tap(result => this.currentLoggedInBenutzer = result),
    switchMapTo(this.getBenutzerRolleDTO(this.currentLoggedInBenutzer.id)))
    .subscribe(benutzerDTO => {
       this.zugriffsrechte = benutzerDTO.zugriffsrechte;
       return of(this.rolleService.hasEditZugriffRechte(this.zugriffsrechte));
    });
  });
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I've added a parenthesis at the end of `switchMapTo...`. Please check.
If you don't want to return a Subscriber, avoid `.subscribe()`. I don't think my code is optimized. Try something like this.

```
hasEditRechte(): Observable<boolean> {
  this.zugriffsrechte = [];
  return this.getCurrentBenutzer().pipe(
    tap(result => this.currentLoggedInBenutzer = result),
    switchMapTo(this.getBenutzerRolleDTO(this.currentLoggedInBenutzer.id)))
    tap(benutzerDTO => this.zugriffsrechte = benutzerDTO.zugriffsrechte)
    map(() => of(this.rolleService.hasEditZugriffRechte(this.zugriffsrechte));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: import {map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {switchMapTo} from 'rxjs/operators/switchMapTo';   I added these imports but it shows:  Property Subscribe does not exist on type OperatorFunction ".subscribe(benutzerDTO => {"  here is red line

Comment: Your code returns Subscription IntelliJ tells me the change the return object from Observable<boolean> to Subscription and then it is ok. But I dont think this is what I need. It should return Observable<boolean>

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: I did it this way with Promise and after that I call the function .then(value => { logic inside})
    hasEditZugriffRechte(): Promise<boolean> {
        return this.getCurrentBenutzer().pipe(
            tap(result => this.currentLoggedInBenutzer = result), switchMapTo(this.getBenutzerRolleDTO(this.currentLoggedInBenutzer.id)))
            .toPromise().then((value: BenutzerRolleDTO) =>
                this.rolleService.hasEditRechte(value.zugriffsrechte));
    }

Comment: Your last idea does ist not correct because the second "tap" how is it connected? there is not dot and if I put dot still does not work.